How to install gnome extensions?
I was trying to install gnome extensions but when i was trying to install chrome gnome extensions a error was coming. Please help.
anshul@Anshul:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for anshul: 
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                      
Get:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [119 kB]     
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Hit:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Get:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages [1,597 kB]
Get:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main i386 Packages [616 kB]
Get:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1,070 kB]
Get:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe i386 Packages [699 kB]
Fetched 4,212 kB in 5s (904 kB/s)                       
Reading package lists... Done
anshul@Anshul:~$ sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: The package code needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.


If the linked duplicate question doesn't help, please edit your question explaining why that didn't work and we'll reopen the question and try to help you out.
